# Custom template functions not found in html template

Tags: html, go

I render templates this way:

```
  func renderTemplate(...........) {
    rt := template.Must(template.ParseFiles(
        fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", templatesPath, baseLayoutPath),
        fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", templatesPath, tplName)))

      err := rt.ExecuteTemplate(w, "base", nil)
      //[................]
  }
```

I want to register a custom function in it:

```
func myTest1(string s) string {
  return "hello: " + s
}


func renderTemplate(...........) {
  rt := template.Must(template.ParseFiles(
              fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", templatesPath, baseLayoutPath),
              fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", templatesPath, tplName))).Funcs(template.FuncMap{"test1": myTest1})
```

This doesn't work:  **"test1" not defined"**

```
  // html template:


  {{range .items}}

    {{.Field1 | test1}}
```

Why not and how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Add the template functions **before** you parse the templates.

From the [html/template docs for Funcs()](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Funcs):

> Funcs adds the elements of the argument map to the template's function map. It must be called before the template is parsed.

```
funcMap := template.FuncMap{"test1":myTest1}
rt := template.Must(template.New("name").Funcs(funcMap).ParseFiles(
          fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", templatesPath, baseLayoutPath),
          fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", templatesPath, tplName)))
```